# What to do if we see cross-posting

Tags: discussion, questions, closing-questions, exact-duplicates

This question

[fitting a distribution to survival curve in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321878/fitting-a-distribution-to-survival-curve-in-r)

has been posted as an exact duplicate on Stack Overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137772/fitting-a-distribution-to-survival-curve

In case one sees a case of cross-posting, what’s the recommendation? Post a comment saying that cross-posting is against the rules? Or is there a “cross-posting” option in the “vote to close” menu?

I won’t vote to close this one though - I have to admit that cross-posting in this case was useful (I'm putting myself in a dangerous position here ;-P) Ben Bolker’s answer, using NLS, arrives at different results than me using log-transformations plus LS. This is to be expected, since the log weights the residuals for small values of `month` more than the residual for larger `month` values. However, I wouldn’t have expected the difference in the estimated curve to be so large.

Comment: There isn't an explicit cross posting close reason, but there is a free text reason under the off topic option. You could do that; if you didn't want to vote to close, you could just leave a comment, & possibly flag to alert the moderators.

Comment: While we're asked not to cross post, if it's not off topic I don't think we'd have a basis to close it. When people flag these I generally just leave a comment for the explaining the policy ("Please don't cross post, choose one best site..." etc, pretty much what it says in the [help/on-topic]). If it's a stats question I often vote to close on SO.

Comment: @gung I see that in the end it was *my* answer (or better, the question I answered) that got closed as off-topic, even though it was (IMO) more on-topic here than on CV :-) but I understand - after all, I myself said that I wouldn't flag the other one, and my answer would have never been accepted, thus closing the question on CV was  the right choice.

Comment: @DeltaIV, if the version on [SO] gets closed / deleted, & the OP says they want the version on [stats.SE] to be the primary Q, I will reopen it. Just let me know.

Comment: @gung I don't think it will, but it's ok, don't worry. Ben Bolker's answer deserves to stay open.

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment yet so I am answering....

I had a question I put on stackoverflow and a user kindly told me that it would better in the crossvalidated forum explaining why. As a result I thanked the person, copied my question over and left a redirecting link on stackoverflow. I am planning on deleting it later, I just wanted to make sure the person saw what I did.

This got me thinking about another question I had and for which I had no answer. Maybe it was in the wrong board. So I copied it over to crossvalidated and this time deleted it from stackoverflow.

So in my relative small experience giving a comment to explain that it is not the best place and why was very helfpul.

Comment: In this situation, you should flag your question, & ask the moderators to migrate it to the site where you think it will be more appropriate.  For example, once there is an upvoted answer, you won't be able to delete your Q.

Comment: Extending on gung's comment, if you are not familiar with migration yet, refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work. Tks.